# Why do I get a 401 Unauthorized when making a HttpWebRequest with the correct credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have a url and a username and password to an external site.
If I access the URL through a browser, an authentication box pops up.  I give it the username and password, and I can get to the page.

I am trying to achieve the same thing through code, using a HttpWebRequest object:

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

`webRequest.GetResponse()` etc…

This used to work before the web sites owners added some protection to the site, and provided me with the username and password.
The WebRequest has a credentials property, which I have been setting as follows:

```
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password")
```

I have also tried:

```
webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", “url domain”)
```

this always result in the error:

“The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.”

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I have no idea what the problem was, nor do I know which solution to accept.  The external hosts changed something at there end, which meant I had to do something completely different at my end.  I want to delete this.

Comment: I would bet that the url was going to http://domain.com and the server redirected to a page like http://domain.com/sites/home.aspx and did not pass the credential.

Answer (score 1):

Using `System.Net.NetworkCredential` might not be effective depending on the authentication model of the resource. It would be helpful to understand the model used by the remote site.

OpenID, Forms Authentication, and Integrated Windows Authentication all work differently. You can attempt to deduce what authentication method they use using tools as @Christoph and @Lex describe, or simply contact the remote web site provider.

If the remote site uses a negotiating protocol, such as Kerberos or NTLM, then the behavior you are experiencing is strange, indeed; however, some other protocols may require you to go about it another way.

Answer (score 0):

try to debug your request with fiddler (www.fiddler2.com).

Therefore you must start Fiddler, and add the Proxy Settings to your Request:

```
webRequest.Proxy = New WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8888")
```

Comment: Using Fiddler can be nontrivial. Network Monitor or Wireshark is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTTP, please simply use Microsoft Network Monitor or Wireshark to capture what kind of 401 message is returned from the web server. It can be 401.3 or another error code which has in fact another meaning.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no privacy concern, you may wish to post the url you are trying to access.

If the URL is malformed, or references an invalid page (or an invalid page + parameters combination) you will sometimes see server errors like this.

I worked with a legacy web app from the state of Michigan and it would throw 400 style errors every time I tried to access a page with the wrong page parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using request filtering on the web server? Can you check the different verbs which are setup to be denied?